# Убогий — почему это синоним нищеты?

Tags: этимология

Убогий — значит "находящийся у Бога", так? Тогда почему же это слово стало символом нищеты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Убогий — значит "находящийся у Бога", так?

Нет. Это слово родственно не "богу", но "богатству". У - праславянская приставка со значением "не", "без". Богатство же с "богом" никак не связано.

(Уточняю: связь есть, но очень древняя, индоевропейская, спасибо указавшему).

Убогий - бедный.

Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. ѹбогъ «бедный; нищий; увечный», ст.-слав. ѹбогъ (греч. πτωχός), укр. убо́гий, болг. убо́г, сербохорв. у̀бог, словенск. ubọ̑g, чешск. ubohý, словацк. úbohý, польск. ubogi; синонимично церк.-слав. небогъ «бедный», образовано с приставкой u-. От *bogъ «богатство». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; 
(Вики)

Comment: Интересно, а есть еще современные слова, в которых у- имеет смысл отрицания?  

А вот, вспомнила "уходить" - подходит? ;-))

Comment: Есть.
И как минимум один интересный: "уже". 
"же" - в праславянском это некий аналог (не точный!) современного "еще".
Подробнее - см Фасмера.

Остальные - надо посмотреть, боюсь навскидку напутать, но есть точно.
Урод, кажется, из этого ряда.

Есть, кстати, версия что современна отрицательная частица "НЕ" может быть родственно этому дреанему "У" как другая ступень разложения индоевропеской частицы с носовым звуком. Но тут копать надо...

Comment: Да оставьте вы уже в покое Задорнова! Он хоть любовь к родному языку пропагандирует, а не западную порнуху!

Comment: Вы думаете - прививает?
Извращенная какая-то любовь...
Но в данном случае (как и в большинстве других) это аллюзия на вполне конкретную его прививку "у русских богатсво - от бога".

Answer (score -2):

«Убогий — значит "находящийся у Бога", так?»

Не «у Бога», раз жив. Убог тот, кто ищет Бога (нищий духом, нуждающийся в вере), просит **у Бога** помощи.

Comment: Нет. "У" здесь древнейшая форма отрицания. Сейчас рудиментарно сохранилась в единичных словах. Убогий - лишенный Бога (милости божией), обделенный.

Comment: Смешно по определению. Лишних у Бога нет.

Comment: Кому смешно по определению, про тех есть хорошая русская поговорка.

Comment: По красивой традиции перешли на личности... Нет слов, остались буквы? Добавлю, если угодно: не лишённый и обделённый, а напротив — у Бога на особом счету, Им избранный, под опекой и призрением.

Comment: Бог «избрал немудрое мира, чтобы посрамить мудрых, и немощное мира избрал Бог, чтобы посрамить сильное; и незнатное мира и уничиженное и ничего не значащее избрал Бог, чтобы упразднить значащее, для того, чтобы никакая плоть не хвалилась пред Богом» (1 Кор. 1:27-29).

Comment: И что теперь???

Comment: Кстати, ещё одна цитата: «Господь убожит и богатит», показывающая, что слова эти одной природы. Только миром они противопоставлены, как нищета и изобилие, хотя «по сп. XV в. (Iерем. 36. 15) Богати = служить.